# The bouncing sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, integer

Let us define a sequence.  We will say that \$a(n)\$ is the smallest number, \$x\$, that has the following properties:

- \$x\$ and \$n\$ are co-prime (they share no factor)
- \$x\$ does not appear earlier in the sequence
- \$|n - x| > 1\$

Unlike most sequences the domain and range of our sequence are the integers *greater than* 1.

---

Let us calculate the first couple of terms.

\$a(2)\$, must be at least **4**, but **4** and **2** share a factor of **2** so \$a(2)\$ must be **5**.

\$a(3)\$, must be at least **5** but **5** is taken by \$a(2)\$, so it is at least **6**, but **6** shares a factor with **3** so it must be at least **7**, **7** fulfills all three requirements thus \$a(3)=7\$.

\$a(4)\$

- **2** Shares a factor
- **3** Too close
- **4** Too close
- **5** Too close
- **6** Shares a factor
- **7** Taken by **a(3)**
- **8** Shares a factor
- **9** is good

\$a(5)\$

- **2** is good

---

### Task

In this challenge you are to write a program that takes a number greater than 1 and returns \$a(n)\$.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with fewer bytes being better.

### Test Cases

Here are the first couple terms of the sequence (They are of course 2 indexed):

```
5,7,9,2,11,3,13,4,17,6,19,8,23,22,21,10,25,12,27,16,15,14
```

### <s>Bonus</s> Fun fact

As proven by Robert Israel on Math.se ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2366358/276060)) this sequence is its own inverse, that means that \$a(a(n)) = n\$ for all n.

### OEIS

After asking this question I submitted this sequence to the OEIS and after a few days it was added.

[OEIS A290151](https://oeis.org/A290151)

Comment: How many values did you compute? (Talking about the bonus)

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix I've been doing it by hand so only the ones shown in the test cases.  I'm currently debugging a program to check larger values.

Comment: As am I... it's not working right now though, my indexing is off (edit:) aand now it's working... the first 1000 are safe xD

Comment: Do you know an upper bound for a(x)?  E.g. a(x) < u*x for some u. Btw the first few million values are safe.

Comment: @nimi I do not know of an upper bound.

Comment: `a = {1, 5}; Do[k = 2; While[Nand[CoprimeQ[n, k], ! MemberQ[a, k], Abs[n - k] >= 2], k++]; AppendTo[a, k], {n, 3, 96}]; Rest@ a (* Michael De Vlieger, Jul 21 2017 *)` - Wow, they're fast, you'd think it'd take longer to post AND implement a sequence for them.

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 61 bytes

```hs
f n=[i|i<-[2..],gcd i n<2,all((/=i).f)[2..n-1],abs(n-i)>1]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBDoMgEAXQq3wTF5AALboVL2JYTGupE3Ek6rJ3p3H93kLn@sm51gQJE/94sFPnXDTf9wyGDJ2hnJV6BNYu6dvE@mjodSqxrEcfm@ZZN2JBwLyjHCwXWmxUkHB/38f6Bw)

I'm fairly new to Haskell, so any golfing tips are appeciated.

Thanks to Wheat Wizard for 2 bytes and nimi for 4 bytes

Explanation:

```hs
f n=[i|i<-[2..],gcd i n<2,all((/=i).f)[2..n-1],abs(n-i)>1]!!0
f n=                                                          -- define a function f :: Int -> Int
    [i|i<-[2..],                                              -- out of positive integers greater than two
                gcd i n<2,                                    -- gcd of i and n is 1
                          all((/=i).f)[2..n-1],               -- i isn't already in the sequence
                                               abs(n-i)>1]    -- and |n-i| > 1
                                                          !!0 -- take the first element
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 42 bytes

```
/oi
\1@/2-&whq&[]w].q-H.t*n$K.qG?*h$KW.!kq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/P5MrxtBB30hXrTyjUC06tjxWr1DXQ69EK0/FW6/Q3V4rQ8U7XE8xu/D/f0MDAA)

#### Explanation

```
/oi
\1@/.........
```

This is a standard template for programs that take a number as input, and output a number, modified to place a 1 on the stack below the input number.

The main part of the program places each number `k` in slot `a(k)` on the tape.  The inner loop computes a(k), and the outer loop iterates over k until a(n) is computed.

```
1       push 1
i       take input
2-&w    repeat n-1 times (push return address n-2 times)
h       increment current value of k
q&[     return tape to position 0
]       move right to position 1
w       push return address to start inner loop
]       move to next tape position
.q-     subtract tape position from k
H       absolute value
.t*     multiply by this amount minus 1
n$K     if zero (i.e., |k-x| = 0 or 1), return to start of inner loop
.qG     GCD(k, x)
?       current value of tape at position: -1 if x is available, or something positive otherwise
*       multiply
h$K     if not -1, return to start of inner loop
W       pop return address without jumping (end inner loop)
.!      store k at position a(k)
k       end outer loop
q       get tape position, which is a(n)
o       output
@       terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 111 bytes

```
(s={};Table[m=2;While[m<3#,If[CoprimeQ[i,m]&&FreeQ[s,m]&&Abs[i-m]>1,s~AppendTo~m;m=3#];m++],{i,2,#}];s[[#-1]])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcbNCoJAEADgh1mQwglxPW4bShB0qxA6DHPQWnOgUXG9ib769vOdPqmmlh8@NDZsvJ0XU1b126FYbe4t/7bPFJwbPPbDyOKuyCAURafRfe//L2qPvBM6pODXYhhc9yz7VYzYTJGROCaYGTSohYxHVLuUaBuFy8jdlORNkt@q7uVQg84ofAA)  2..23 (range mode)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcZNC4IwGADgHzMYhROa0mlNlCDoViB0GO9Ba8MXenVs3kT/@vp4Tg9184DPmJxOu6iXVbVd/7aGdKEeA/52Kpm4OnOefECyd4OCgPNLsN/H/5s@GswJKini1nhvx1c7baRIlwwUZRmIBUUh2AoqGsNyCbDn6RZwnGtXy@MhfQA) or 150 (distinct values)

Answer (score 1):

## VB.NET (.NET 4.5), 222 bytes

```
Function A(n)
Dim s=New List(Of Long)
For i=2To n
Dim c=2
While Math.Abs(i-c)<2Or g(c,i)>1Or s.Contains(c)
c+=1
End While
s.Add(c)
Next
Return s.Last
End Function
Function g(a, b)
Return If(b=0,a,g(b,a Mod b))
End Function
```

I had to roll your own GCD. I also couldn't figure out how to get it to not be an entire function.

GCD is always >= 1, so only need to ignore 1

Took out short-circuiting in the golf because it's shorter

Un-golfed

```
Function Answer(n As Integer) As Integer
    Dim seqeunce As New List(Of Integer)
    For i As Integer = 2 To n
        Dim counter As Integer = 2
        ' took out short-circuiting in the golf because it's shorter
        ' GCD is always >= 1, so only need to ignore 1
        While Math.Abs(i - counter) < 2 OrElse GCD(counter, i) > 1 OrElse seqeunce.Contains(counter)
            counter += 1
        End While
        seqeunce.Add(counter)
    Next
    Return seqeunce.Last
End Function

' roll your own GCD
Function GCD(a, b)
    Return If(b = 0, a, GCD(b, a Mod b))
End Function
```

Comment: It blows my mind that .NET doesn't have a GCD built in outside of the BigInteger class.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 33 bytes (non-competing?)<sup>†</sup>

```
ò2 rÈc_aY >1«XøZ «Yk øZk}a+2}[] o
```

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=8jIgcshjX2FZID4xq1j4WiCrWWsg+FprfWErMn1bXSBv&inputs=Mg==,Mw==,NA==,NQ==,Ng==,Nw==,OA==,OQ==,MTA=)

<sub><sup>†</sup> I [fixed a bug in the Japt Interpreter](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/commit/223f6dbc196b309312750eabaab31018409a7113) while working on this solution. [This meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/69583)
 from a year ago deems this answer non-competing, but [this newer meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/69583) is pushing for more freedom in this. Regardless, I spent too much time on this to scrap it.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2IŸεDU°2Ÿ¯KʒX¿}ʒXα1›}θDˆ}θ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyPPojnNbXUJDtIyO7ji03vvUpIhD@2uB5LmNho8adtWe2@Fyug1IAlWaAgA) or [output the first \$n\$ terms as list](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyPPojnNbXUJDtIyO7ji03vvUpIhD@2uB5LmNho8adtWe2@Fyuq0WqM4UAA). (NOTE: `°` is obviously extremely slow, so replaced with `T*` in the TIO links (\$10*n\$ instead of \$10^n\$).)

**Explanation:**

```python
2IŸ               # Create a list in the range [2, input]
   ε              # Map each value `y` to:
    DU            #  Store a copy of `y` in variable `X`
    °2Ÿ           #  Create a list in the range [10**`y`,2]
       ¯K         #  Remove all values already in the global_array
       ʒX¿}       #  Only keep values with a greatest common divider of 1 with `X`
       ʒXα1›}     #  Only keep values with an absolute difference larger than 1 with `X`
             θ    #  After these filters: keep the last (the smallest) element
              Dˆ  #  And add a copy of it to the global_array
   }θ             # After the map: only leave the last value
                  # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 22 bytes

```
!¡λḟ§&oε⌋o>1≠→L¹`-N);1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9odXNr/21vd1Ms4oKB4oCmMiAyM/8hwqHOu@G4n8KnJm/OteKMi28@MeKJoOKGkkzCuWAtTik7Mf//)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 21 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

It pains me to have to invoke a function without a shortcut - can't remember the last time I had to, if ever - but it worked out shorter than any other method I could come up with.

```
@W{WjY «ZøW ©ÓWaY}a}g
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QFd7V2pZIKta%2bFcgqdNXYVl9YX1n&input=Mg)